# How do I return (k) amount of bits a binary strings in a file?

Tags: python, file, binary, bit

Essentially, if I were to type in 4 for n and 4 for k, it should return 4 lines of a 4 bit binary string in a file.

Instead, it returns four lines of binary, but in ascending order of bits. (So first line has one bit, second line has two, third line has three, and so on.)

Here is my code:

```
import random
def makeStrings():
    fileName = str(input("file:"))
    outputFile = open(fileName, "w")
    userInput = str(input("k:"))
    anotherinput = str(input("n:"))
    counter = 0
    while (counter < int(anotherinput)):
        stringy = ""
        for i in range(int(userInput)): 
            RandoNumber=int(random.random()*2)
            stringy=stringy+str(RandoNumber) 
            outputFile.write(str(stringy) + "\n")
            counter = counter +1
    outputFile.close()
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
    stringy = ""
    for i in range(int(userInput)): 
        RandoNumber=int(random.random()*2)
        stringy=stringy+str(RandoNumber) 
        outputFile.write(str(stringy) + "\n")
        counter = counter +1
```

You are looping up to userInput, but printing every time. (In this case, `outputFile.write`ing every time.)

You need to wait until your `for` loop finishes before writing a value out to the outputFile. That way, your `stringy` variable will have the correct length.

Answer (score 0):

You mishandled your loop indices.  Your inner loop writes every addition to the string.  Your outer loop runs in parallel with the inner loop; **counter** is incremented every time through the inner loop.  Try this instead.  I simplified a few lines for testing.

```
userInput = 4
anotherinput = 4
for counter in range(int(anotherinput)):
    stringy = ""
    for i in range(int(userInput)): 
        RandoNumber=int(random.random()*2)
        stringy=stringy+str(RandoNumber) 
    print(str(stringy) + "\n")
# outputFile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew it was a simple fix, but I couldn't figure out.